# Why does Adobe Acrobat DC Pro display some blue color in a PDF as black?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

The PDF in the screenshot beneath can be [downloaded](http://www.mediafire.com/file/1iil649lu2he1ij/Criminal_Law_%25282018_8_ed%2529.pdf/file). p. 2 is on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=WM8oCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=eu+law+craig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiglsn1lsLfAhVm5oMKHSLJBSgQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), which substantiates that the chapter heading and passage subheadings are  blue, as correctly displayed on Foxit PhantomPDF and Nitro Pro beneath. But why doesn't Acrobat DC Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. I accidentally had 'Replace Document Colors' ticked, in Edit → Preferences → Accessibility.